# "Nitpick at someone" vs "nitpick about something"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Tell me please if the following sentence is correct.

> My teacher is constantly nitpicking at me.

I have looked up the verb *nitpick* in a few dictionaries and what I saw is that *nitpick* is used with the preposition *about*, but then there must be a thing or some kind of work that people nitpick about. For example:

> My boss was nitpicking about the work I had done.

So is it possible to say *nitpick at someone* meaning *finding fault with someone*?

Comment: As a footnote, an alternative is to use the adjective: _My teacher is constantly nitpicky with me._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but in the experience of this US English speaker we usually nitpick at a thing, not a person, like "nitpicking at the work I had done."

[We also often use *nitpick* with no preposition, like "nitpicking the work", which is actually equally common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nitpick%20*&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cnitpick%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnitpick%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnitpick%20or%3B%2Cc0) For example,

> [Their real mission was to nitpick the unit on the slightest thing.](https://books.google.com/books?id=bc3GAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT98&dq=%22nitpick%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic2q2V__XaAhXrT98KHcpXAOMQ6AEIXDAJ)

Comment: I've heard it used where a person is being nitpicked at. *Why are you always nitpicking at me?*  https://books.google.com/books?id=sTJLAQAAIAAJ&q=%22nitpicking+at%22&dq=%22nitpicking+at%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS6-6KiPbaAhVKdt8KHcDuDAkQ6AEIPDAE